# Cannot view form fields of a PDF document

Tags: windows, pdf

I have this really weird and annoying issue. I have template PDF document that I send to clients which contains form fields which needs to be filled out. However when the client's send back the completed PDF form, the form fields are blank!

It just looks like the template I gave to them - empty.

What's the reason for me not being able to view these form fields? I am using Adobe Reader XI. Also, the PDF I get send back has some sort of security protection if this helps.

[image: Example]

I cannot show you an example because well. . . my example will be blank!

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not that the e-mail client fails to attach the updated PDF?

Comment: What PDF viewer/editor are your clients using?

Comment: Nope, pretty certain it's not that because it happens a lot of the time - and sometimes we have to tell them to send it into a different format (e.g. Word Doc) @AFH

Comment: One of the PDF's that a client sent to us was from **1.7, Adobe Extension Level 5 (Acrobat 9.x)** @Karan

Comment: So they're filling the form using Acrobat 9.x? It should be visible in Reader XI then. What sort of security protection have they added?

Comment: I've added a picture of the security tab when I open the PDF @Karan